# Coolant, filling while draining

Tags: coolant, cooling-system, flush, drain

2020 F150 3.5L Ecoboost. Can I fill the coolant reservoir while draining coolant?

The bottom of the radiator has a drain valve and I'm wondering why I can't set up the new coolant to flow into the reservoir while I drain it. I don't mind if I waste a gallon, it would be great if I did since it'd be flushing through.

Essentially using gravity to flush and not let air in.

As far as I can tell, even using a vacuum filler leaves plenty of air since you can't vacuum out air between metal cavities.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure if you can control draining it well enough not to run dry in the reservoir. But, theoretically, sure; that's how power steering systems are usually flushed.
It might be hard to get everything out without the water pump running depending on how the cooling system is set up

Comment: The drain valve is a large red knob, and I'll be attaching a long tube so controlling the pressure could also be done via a secondary valve from my tube. Aw yeah, I'm excited.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Still, are you sure you'll actually get everything to flush that way and that you're not just flushing the "shortest path" from reservoir to drain valve over and over again?

Comment: No, I know I'm not flushing everything. I just want to skip some of the air nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can drain while filling. It's quick and doesn't let any air in.

I recommend doing it twice after driving it at full temperature in between to circulate the coolant.

It's so simple, just flushing a couple gallons more often is probably what I'll do.

Answer (score 0):

The engine draws coolant from the reservoir based on thermal contraction (as the engine cools), not gravity.  The engine therefore must be off to draw coolant from the reservoir.  If you run the engine while draining the fluid, the reservoir coolant will not be used and the cooling system will run dry, the engine will run hot.

Follow the engine's shop manual procedures for draining/filling coolant and bleeding the system of air bubbles.

Comment: Rephrase your answer to not assume the engine would be on during the process of draining and filling. I have no idea why you're talking about the engine being on in relation to my question.